# Keep server receiving numbers from client

Tags: java

I am trying to send numbers through ObjectOutputStream, the variable number will be incremented when I click a button, so when the number is `1`, the server will receive, but when I click the button again and the number is `2`, this last is not received by the server and next numbers neither.

Class client sends:

```
counter++;
oos.writeObject(counter);
```

Class server receives:

```
counter = (int) ois.readObject();
```

Then depends on the number the server receives, it will be running some conditions with instructions.

```
 if(counter==1){ //instructions}
 .
 .
```

But as mentioned before, the server only receives number `"1"`, the next numbers don't receive.

Can you help me?